# Comparing a list to one or more lists: how to specify at what index are they located in the first list? in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a handful of lists, such as:

```
List Vars<string>
List Units<string>
```

which have to be compared to the following ones:

```
List vars<string>
List units<string>
```

Now, the problem is, I also have to store the index these differences are at, for eg.:

```
Vars = 1, 2, 4, 5
vars = 1, 4, 2, 6
```

In this case, I would need to store the 5 from the 1st list(will have to change it to 6).

I did find how to tell if there are differences between these, but I can't get to actually get the index they're located in their own list.

```
var unitsDifferences = Units.Except(unit).Union(unit.Except(Units)).ToList();
```

The lists, as shown in the example above aren't in the same order, sometimes the 1st element of the 1st list is at the end of the 2nd one, or vice-versa, so using for or some other cycle will be really slow, especially that I have to look over thousands of elements.

I'm pretty new to C# and would really appreciate any help that's given.

EDIT:

```
        var firstDiff = TXTHandler.unit
            .Select((i, v) => new { Index = i, Value = v })
            .Where(p => !setVars.Contains(p.Value.ToString()))
            .Select(p => p.Index)
            .ToList(); //   
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", setVars));
```

Prints the values, not the indexes of them.

Comment: i think the second line in your example should say `units = 1, 4, 2, 6`, correct?

Comment: also, just to assert ; the problem here is that finding the differences between the two lists takes too long with your provided linq expression?

Comment: Vars and vars, they're two different lists, but yes, you could name them units as well(in my code they're named in a different way, was just trying to explain myself a bit more by giving those examples). Problem is, that with the .Except method I can just tell there are differences, but I can't tell where are these located in their own lists. Some values appear multiple times, for eg. there'll be more than one "1" in that List, so it's not really possible to check the list(s) for that value, and change it if it's the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with a `FirstOrDefault`, like this:

```
// This is inefficient
var firstDiff = vars
    .Select((v, i) => new {Index = i, Value = v}) // Pair up values and indexes
    .FirstOrDefault(p => !Vars.Contains(p.Value)) // Pick first missing value
    ?.Index; // Select index using ?. because FirstOrDefault could return null
```

To make this more efficient, construct a set from `Vars` first. This will make the algorithm O(n) instead of O(n<sup>2</sup>):

```
var setVars = new HashSet<string>(Vars);
var firstDiff = vars
    .Select((v, i) => new {Index = i, Value = v})
    .FirstOrDefault(p => !setVars.Contains(p.Value))
    ?.Index; //           ^^^^^^^
```

> How do I get indexes of all the differences?

Replace `FirstOrDefault` with `Where` and `Select`:

```
var setVars = new HashSet<string>(Vars);
var allDiffs = vars
    .Select((v, i) => new {Index = i, Value = v})
    .Where(p => !setVars.Contains(p.Value))
    .Select(p => p.Index)
    .ToList();
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/iBLCF9)

Comment: p.value.ToString()* Also, how do I later access the Index or i that was given in here? And how about getting the index of all the differences? (it only gave me the first one)

Comment: @LeventeBoda The index you get is the index into `vars`. Check it for `null` before accessing, because it is `Nullable<int>`. See the edit for getting all indexes.

Comment: Edited the post with the code, hashSet stores the values instead of the actual indexes, don't really understand this LINQ, where are the indexes stored?

Comment: @LeventeBoda That's because you printed `setVars` instead of `allDiffs`.

Comment: There was a bit of a mix-up, Select(i, v) instead of Select(v, i) (first value is string by default, while second is integer), now allDiffs havethe correct values, but whatever I do, it'll only print the values instead of the indexes ( select(p => p.Index) or p.Value are the same practically) - any suggestions?

Comment: @LeventeBoda Yes, I spotted it when making a demo. It prints indexes now (see demo).

Comment: Yay, thanks a lot, you've been really helpful! :) Works like a charm! (by the way, for some reason, it mattered which list is [at]setVars and which one was at [at]allDiffs, no idea why, but I'm glad I decided to swap them up)

Answer (score 0):

Found a better solution if anyone ever tries to solve something like this so boldly.
I've created two classes and made a list of them.

```
class KeysParams
    {
        public string name;
        public string unit;
        public int value;
        public string path;
        public bool ok;
    }
class VarParams
    {
        public string name;
        public string unit;
        public int value;
        public string path;
        public bool ok;
    }

    List<KeysParams> systemKeys = new List<KeysParams>();
    List<VarParams> varKeys = new List<VarParams>();
```

If it needs to be compared to one another, you can simply sort them by the name for eg.:

```
systemKeys = systemKeys.OrderBy(b => varKeys.FindIndex(a => a.name == b.name)).ToList();
```

This will sort the first list after the second one's .name